# Rattle R package: difference between risk and weight variable role?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining

What is the difference between the risk and weight attribute role in the Rattle R data mining package?

Comment: `Rattle` package as far as I know is only GUI for data mining R packages. So maybe it is worth to looking for an answer in the corresponding package which uses mentioned parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The help section of the rattle interface explains this,

The risk variable is used in the evaluate tab when creating a risk chart, the weight attribute is used to give weightings to observations and is used when creating models, you can also specify a weighting formula on the data tab.